# Matlab - Access cell array by name

Tags: arrays, matlab, dynamic, syntax, cell

I wrote several cell arrays I read from txt-files in cell arrays within the MATLAB Workspace. I wrote a cell array 'Names', containing the names of the other cell arrays I assigned. The txt-files can have varying names, therfore I want to use this dynamic naming.

Now I would like to the cell arrays dynamically by using the name (string) from 'Names'. Is this possible? Which syntax do I have to use?

Logically Names{i} gives back the name of the cell array in position i. However using Names{i}.n does not work.
I could not find anything in the MATLAB documentation either..

Comment: dynamic naming is a bad, bad idea.

Comment: stating something without reference or explanation does not help anybody though

Comment: A workaround would be to simply write the data directly into txt files and open them sequentially

Comment: You can have a quick google to see why it is a bad idea, apologies, I dont have time to collect that information, just wanted to make you aware of it

Comment: What suppose to be the meaning of `Names{i}.n`?You try to access to a struct, named [the content in Names{i}], that has a field named "n"?

Comment: exactly Adiel, that is what it is supposed to mean

Comment: So it works for me: `s.f=1;
s.g=2;
N{1}=s;
N{1}.f` gives `1`.

Comment: That is correct, if you access a struct with known field names. However it does not work for cell arrays to acess fields by number.

Comment: Which number..? fields has names, I can't get the point. maybe you mean to "dynamic field names"? e.g., in my example if we had also `d='f'`, you can access with `N{1}.(d)`

Comment: I am reading various text files and wirting information in  cell arrays. The name of the cell array is also read from within the text file. Dependant on the content inside the text file, each row of the cell array has either a value assigned to it, or a variable name with it's value. I am trying to access a certain field in a cell array, the name of the cell array is within the cell array 'Names'  and the cells inside do not necessarily have names assigned to them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i just worked around by writing the data directly to other text files. This way I can access and read the text files sequentially by using the file names.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is not clear. You say that you store names in a variable, but say that you do can use it for access the data. You talk about cell arrays, but ask about structs... I did my best, I afraid that I can't help more unless you'll give some specific examples.

Comment: Cell array has no fields. Check again what exactly you need.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think what you probably need is a Map. You can store each cell array that is read in from a file in the map, using the filename as the map key. For example: `m = containers.Map; cellarray1 = {'a', 'b'}; cellarray2 = {'c', 'd'}; m('filename1') = cellarray1; m('filename2') = cellarray2; m('filename1')`

Comment: Stuff everything inside one more level of variable: for example load the file 'somefile' into `data.somefile`, and 'thatfile' into `data.thatfile`.  Then you can use dynamic fieldnames to access them: `data.(Names{1})`.  You can even ditch the separate array `Names` by just extracting it directly from that structure (using fieldnames).  Also keeps your workspace from getting clogged, or existing variables from getting overwritten if get unlucky with a filename.

Comment: Thank you Peter! That works really well!